# Wsdl2apex - Some values not received by SAP

Tags: wsdl2apex, enterprise-wsdl

**Explanation:**
Some new fields have been added to the 3rd party system and we got a new WSDL file. Instead of generating a new wsdl2apex class, we needed to make changes to the same wsdl2apex class because it is already in use at multiple places. We generated a new wsdl2apex class and copied the extra code from it to the old wsdl2apex class.

**Problem:**
While sending data from salesforce to the third party system, the old field values are received correctly but the new field values are not received. On debugging, I found out that all field values are populated in salesforce while sending.

**Example:**
The third party system has 5 old fields and 2 new fields in WSDL. I generate a new wsdl2apex class and copy extra code to the old wsdl2apex class. I populate all the 7 fields and send them to the 3rd party system from salesforce. I debug and see that all field values are populated in salesforce and sent. In the 3rd party system, I receive values of only 5 old fields and not of the 2 new fields. The 3rd party system is SAP. I am not able to figure out why it's happening. Am I missing something? Please guide. Thankyou.

**Things I tried:**

- There is no problem with the target endpoint as the 5 old values are received by the 3rd party system.
- Generating new wsdl2apex class with the same name doesn't work
- Creating a different version of webservice doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have also updated the `field_order_type_info` for each class that contains the field data and that each property has a corresponding `*_type_info` string array.

You might have and have populated the properties on the Apex class, but without those two corresponding details `WebServiceCallout.invoke` won't include the field values in the resulting SOAP request.